# Rename or remove tag [arangoimp]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There are currently 10 questions tagged with [arangoimp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arangoimp). It is one of the tools that ship with ArangoDB:
https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs.html

The tool was renamed to `arangoimport` in version 3.4, released in late 2018:
https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/release-notes-upgrading-changes34.html#client-tools

The tag should be renamed or potentially be removed (there are no tags for the other tools).